# Correct codomain for the function $f(x,y,z)e^{i\phi}$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, notation

Suppose I have a function $f:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and I now multiply $f$ with $e^{i\phi}$ so I have $f(x,y,z)e^{i\phi}$.

**Question 1:**
I want to denote $f(x,y,z)e^{i\phi}$ with a new function name, say $F$. But what is the codmain, is it the complex numbers because of the factor $e^{i\phi}$? Should I write
$$
F:\mathbb R^3  \rightarrow \mathbb R, \quad F(x,y,z)=f(x,y,z)e^{i\phi} \tag 1
$$
or

$$
F:\mathbb R^3  \rightarrow \mathbb C, \quad F(x,y,z)=f(x,y,z)e^{i\phi} \tag 2
$$

**Question 2:** If I have $F(x,y,z)=f(x,y,z)e^{i\phi}$, is $\phi$ also a variable? I.e. is $F$ actually a function of four variables
$$
F:\mathbb R^4  \rightarrow \mathbb R, \quad F(x,y,z,\phi)=f(x,y,z)e^{i\phi} \tag 3
$$
or

$$
F:\mathbb R^4  \rightarrow \mathbb C, \quad F(x,y,z,\phi)=f(x,y,z)e^{i\phi} \tag 4
$$

Comment: Unless stated clearly, $\phi$ can be either a variable (in which case, $f(x,y,z)e^{i\phi}$ is a function in four variables) or a fixed value (so the variables are three)

Comment: As for the codomain, $e^{i\phi}$ is a complex number which need not be real in general, so the codomain should indeed be $\mathbb{C}$.